# Synchronized message queue

Tags: c#, .net, message-queue

I have a system where a set of operations need to be done, each operation has a type and an entity. Operations for each entity can be done independently, but within entity the order of types does matter. Operations on a type can start only when all operations of the previous type have finished. Operations usually take some data from database, process it, store results in the database again.

How can I achieve this effect (preferably within the .NET world) assuming the amount of operations will require use of many machines in parallel?

P.S.
Right now I am using service bus, each message is an operation-entity-type combination. This does not meet my needs at all since the order is not enforced and it's not clear when an operation connected with a message has actually finished.

EDIT:
I need to find a logical way of processing those operations in the right order keeping everything (which can be) parallel.

Example:
I need to do 3 types of operations (T1-T3) for 2 entities (E1, E2). There can be many operations having the same type and entity.

```
-- Entity 1
[T1, E1][T1, E1][T1, E1][T1, E1] - 4 operations Type 1, Entity 1
[T2, E1][T2, E1] - 2 ops, Type 2, Entity 1
[T3, E1] - 1 operation, Type 3, Entity 1
-- Entity 2
[T2, E2][T2, E2]
[T3, E2]
```

Generally I can process entity 1 in parallel to entity 2. I can do each specific [Tx, Ex] in parallel too (for example all [T2, E1]). I need to keep order of types, T1->T2->T3. T2 operations need to wait until all T1 operations have **finished** within an entity.

Comment: Do you need to synhronously provide some response to those messages, or it's fire and forget?

Comment: The messages carry information about work needed to be done, which results are stored in a database.

Comment: So when message arrives, you can lookup (in memory or in database) if given entity is in the right state for operation to be applied. If yes - apply. If not - cache operation in memory. When another message arrives, do the same but then look up (in memory) if there are pending operations for this entity which arrived earlier but not yet applied. If yes - perform the same sequence for them (if NOW it can be applied - apply, otherwise wait until next time).

Comment: You suggest a kind of synchronization via database. Storing messages in ram will be problematic after a machine restart/program crash/service restart as it will result is a loss of messages and no way of restarting them.

Comment: Yes, but you need to use some persistent storage anyway, because what if message arrived and service crashed before you applied it to database - it's also lost. Unless you use some message broker (like RabbitMQ) which allows you to notify queue manager (rabbit) when you have actually processed the message and it can be removed from storage.

Comment: I don't really understand. If you want parallelism but you also want ordering, then you're getting no advantages from parallelism since the other operations cannot complete before the previous required operation is done. Maybe I'm misunderstanding. 

EDIT: I'm probably interpreting your question wrong, but have you looked into transactions in MSMQ (which is .NET in the System.Messaging namespace?). The MSMQ transactions effectively work like a transaction in a database.

Comment: @coolboyjules Imagine a `Dictionary<Foo, IEnumerable<Bar>>`, he wants to process each individual `IEnumerable<Bar>` synchronously, but multiple `IEnumerable<Bar>`s can be processed in parallel.

Comment: Service Broker is a queuing solution built into SQL Server which has in-order processing. If you have a conversation per entity type, the conversations can be read in parallel by different threads/tasks/stored procedure activations. Service Broker may be especially attractive if the databases you're doing work on are in fact SQL Server instances, since it integrates easily with triggers and the like. Building an actual working solution out of this, however, has to be left as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use separate queues for each type of operation (message). You process this queues in order and only if previous queue is empty. 
Eg. there are 3 queues A, B and C. Consumer checks if there is any message in A queue. If it is - consumer gets it and process. If not - it's checks B queue. And so on.
But there still could be a problem with last message from A queue - it may still process when messages from B queue will start.

Similar solutions - use message priority. But problem with last message still remains.

Comment: This would require additional synchronization especially when you introduce parallelism and the last message becomes last n messages.

Answer (score 1):

How about you keep a state in your entity, that induces which types of operations are allowed to be performed.

You'll have some worker that will distribute the operations over different threads, and will change the state when there are no more operations of a certain type to be done.

I think it's possible to check if started threads are finished, but you might even want to add state to the operations too, (e.g. Queued, InProgress, Done).

You can just query if an entity still has operations of a certain type that are not 'Done', and when they are all Done, update the state of the Entity, allowing the next type of operation with state Queued to be dequeued and processed.

### Note

This only works if the invariant holds that it is not possible to go from one state to a previous one, meaning that this only works when it is *not* possible for an entity to process T1 operations after it has done T2 operations. In practice this means that it should not be allowed that an entity gets new operations assigned after it has started being processed.

Comment: I understand you suggest distributing it over threads in one machine. This will not scale well though. Sorry for not specifying this "requirement" in the question.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on how machines get distributed their tasks?

Comment: Right now? Azure service bus. What would be the best way for this scenario - I don't know.